# compare dictionary objects and get the one with lowest value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

so i have this variable:

```
var productsInCart = (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)Session["ProductsInCart"];
```

The dictionarys inside the list have 3 keys. "unit_price", "name" and "quantity" with different values in them.

How can i in the best way get the dictionary objekt with the lowest unit_price and turn that unit_price into an int variable. I have no ide how to do this i have tried but have come absolutly nowhere can somebody help me?

Comment: What did you try?  What problems did you have with your implementation?  Additionally, why are you storing your data in this manner?  You should really have a custom object, rather than a dictionary, to store those values.

Comment: Your question is very unclear...

Comment: i just wanna find out which of the dictionary have the lowest unit_price. i have nothing to show you because what i tried was so bad. I dont even know where to start

Comment: Use a ViewModel to keep your sanity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ should be quite easy. I'm assuming you need to parse unit_prices to int, be careful: This will throw an exception if the data cannot be converted to an int.

```
int result =  productsInCart.Select(x => int.Parse(x["unit_price"])).Min();
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is longer, but It manages empty collections and invalid numeric keys

```
var dict_object = productsInCart.Where(x => int.TryParse($"{x["unit_price"]}", out i))
    .OrderBy(x => (int)x["unit_price"]).FirstOrDefault();
int u_price = (dict_object != null) ? (int)dict_object["unit_price"] : 0;
```